# libtool error: only absolute run-paths are allowed

Tags: clang, clang++, automake, libtool, rpath

Getting this error during "make" in [mpich](https://github.com/pmodels/mpich)

```
GEN      lib/libmpi.la
libtool: error: only absolute run-paths are allowed
```

Compiler being used is clang (the code builds fine with gcc). Any idea what this error could be due to?
Here is the configure command:

```
./configure '--prefix=$PWD/BIN' '--with-device=ch3:nemesis:mxm' '--with-mxm=/home/xyz/software/hpcx-v1.9.5-gcc-inbox-redhat7.3-x86_64/mxm' '--disable-spawn' '--disable-ft-tests' '--enable-g=all' '--enable-nemesis-dbg-localoddeven' '--enable-large-tests' '--disable-perftest' 'CC=clang' 'CXX=clang++' 'FC=gfortran' 'F77=gfortran' --cache-file=/dev/null --disable-fortran
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is the evaluation of `$PWD` within the quotes. If you replace

```
./configure '--prefix=$PWD/BIN' ...
```

with

```
./configure --prefix=$PWD/BIN ...
```

you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error as well when building a different piece of software. The solution for me was to enclose the shell variable in `--prefix=` with `{}`:

```
./configure --prefix=${PWD}/BIN
```